# How to set text in the middle (horizontally and vertically)?

Tags: html, css

[image]

This is my html and css

```
<div id="name">
<p>TEST TEST TEXT</p>
</div>

#name{
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #019fde;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

How to set text in the middle (horizontally and vertically)?

Comment: Typical and often asked question, have a look into the search results http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vertical+align

Answer (score 2):

If it's just one line you can use `line-height`. Set `line-height` to the same height as the element (50px in this case) and your text will be in the middle.

To align the text centrally, simply use `text-align:center;`

Answer (score 1):

This will do it:

```
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Z8S8H/

Answer (score 0):

you could also not bother wrapping the `p` in a `div` and simply give the `p` tag consistent padding on the top and the bottom that will achieve your desired height while also setting `text-align:center`.